# Generalize way to handle response and error for all web-service calls

Tags: android, rx-java2

I am trying to create generlize approach to handle following

1. response from webservice
2. to handle HTTP error and custom errors

for that i have written following code and crated callbacks to handle response `ResponseCallback` and errors `ErrorCallback`.

To fetch data related to nutrition or any other objects i can use the same callbacks.

```
    Request request = new Request();
    request.setAccess_token("d80fa6bd6f78cc704104d61146c599bc94b82ca225349ee68762fc6c70d2dcf0");
    request.setStart_date("2018-06-01T00:00:00");
    Flowable<Response> fitnessFlowable = new WebRequest()
            .getRemoteClient()
            .create(FitnessApi.class)
            .getFitnessData("5b238abb4d3590001d9b94a8",request.toMap());

      fitnessFlowable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .takeUntil(response->response.getSummary().getNext()!=null)
            .doOnNext(new ResponseCallback())
            .doOnError(new ErrorCallback<Throwable>())
            .subscribe();
```

*Response callback*

```
public  class ResponseCallback<T extends Response> implements Consumer<Response> {


    @Override
    public void accept(Response response) throws Exception {
        if(response ==null || response.getFitness() == null || response.getFitness().isEmpty()) {


            new Exception("NUll response");

        }

        RxBus.getInstance().send(response.getFitness());
       Log.e("Data","accept");
        try(Realm r = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
            r.executeTransaction((realm) -> {
                realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(response.getFitness());
            });
        }
    }
}
```

*Error callback*

```
public class ErrorCallback <T extends Throwable> implements Consumer<Throwable> {

    public static final String TAG = "ErrorCallback";
    @Override
    public void accept(Throwable e) throws Exception {

        if (e instanceof HttpException) {
            ResponseBody body = ((HttpException) e).response().errorBody();
            try {
                Response response=  LoganSquare.parse(body.byteStream(),Response.class);

                if(response.getErrors() !=null)
                    if(response.getErrors().size() > 0)
                      Log.e(TAG , response.getErrors().get(0).getErrors() );

            } catch (IOException t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else if (e instanceof SocketTimeoutException) {

            Log.e(TAG , e.getMessage() );

        }else if (e instanceof IOException) {

            Log.e(TAG , e.getMessage() );
        }else{
            Log.e(TAG , e.getMessage() );
        }
    }
}
```

Two problems here i am trying to address

1. To handle response and error i need to make two separate callbacks. is there any other way where i can handle response and error in callback rather than creating two separate one
2. When should i dispose the subscribe in above code because you can see in my code that my subscribe is hagging.

I have refereed  [this link](https://medium.com/mindorks/rxjava2-and-retrofit2-error-handling-on-a-single-place-8daf720d42d6) to design generalize approach.

Comment: why don't you extend DisposableObserver like discribed in the tuto?

Comment: i don't know how it will work with `Flowable` if you have any idea how to use it with my example then do suggest a way

Comment: It isn't clear at all what you're trying to do but you're breaking the observable chain for one thing which is a huge red flag. Extend the DisposableObserver as recommended in the tutorial you linked. Why do you think it won't work with a Flowable?

Comment: what i am trying to do is to isolate the webservice call and the UI callbacks. once my code done with the webservice call , inserting data into database then i want to acknowledge the UI. DisposableObserver works with Observable so not sure how i can use it with Flowable

Comment: the reason why i am isolating is i dont want to write same calls for all the web service call

Comment: Use DisposableSubscriber instead of DisposableObserver.

Comment: i will try that , what you mean by `breaking the observable chain` can you please explain as i want to understand what am i doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

**Addressing Question #1** -

> To handle response and error i need to make two separate callbacks. is
>   there any other way where i can handle response and error in callback
>   rather than creating two separate one

In the Clean Architecture approach, your webservice would be defined as a RemoteDataSource (likely adhering to a 'DataSource' protocol. The RemoteDataSource should serialize it's result in a class format - if you are able to use Kotlin, then a [sealed class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html) is a great option here (if Kotlin isn't an option - :( - then look at Enums or IntDefs). See the following:

```
/**
 * The return state from the Data Layer
 */
sealed class ServiceResult {

    data class Success(val list: List<MySerializedObject>) : ServiceResult()

    data class Error(val reason: Throwable?) : ServiceResult()
}
```

This allows you to pass a single state back up from the Data layer, through the Domain layer (where you may do additional logic based off of the result), and finally into the View layer, where the Presenter can switch on this as such:

```
  when (result) {
                    is ServiceResult.Success -> {
                        serializeToViewModel(result) // VM to the Adapter
                    }
                    is ServiceResult.Error -> result.reason?.let {
                        PartialViewState.Error(it) // Can be rendered immediately
                    } 
                }
```

Your Presenter can then call a render method on the view like such:

```
            ... subscribeOn() etc
            .subscribe({ view?.render(it) }, { view?.render(ViewState(error = it)) })
```

The render method of your view can then perform a small amount of logic on switching between which viewstates to render, which error message to show, etc.

FYI, the architecture that I am using relies heavily on [MVI by Hans Dorfmann](http://hannesdorfmann.com/android/mosby3-mvi-1)... I strongly recommend it.

Comment: i am not using kotlin